# How to rotate a triangle?

Tags: ios

I'm struggling with rotating a triangle resulting from a UIRotationGestureRecognizer.  If you could look over my approach and offer suggestions, I'd greatly appreciate it.

I ask the gesture recognizer object for the rotation, which the documentation says is returned in radians.

My strategy had been to think of each vertex as a point on a circle that exists between the center of the triangle and the vertex, and then use the radians of rotation to find the new point on that circumference.  I'm not totally sure this is a valid approach, but I wanted to at least try it.  Visually I'd know whether or not it was working.

Here's the code I created in that attempt:

```
- (CGPoint)rotateVertex:(CGPoint)vertex byRadians:(float)radians
{
    float deltaX = center.x - vertex.x;
    float deltaY = center.y - vertex.y;
    float currentAngle = atanf( deltaX / deltaY );
    float newAngle = currentAngle + radians;
    float newX = cosf(newAngle) + vertex.x;
    float newY = sinf(newAngle) + vertex.y;
    return CGPointMake(newX, newY);
}
```

When executed, there's a slight rotation at the beginning, but then as I continue rotating my fingers the vertices just start getting farther away from the center point, indicating I'm confusing something here.

I looked at what the CGContextRotateCTM could do for me, but ultimately I need to know what the vertices are after the rotation, so just rotating the graphics context doesn't appear to leave me with those changed coordinates.

I also tried the technique described [here](http://i.thiyagaraaj.com/tutorials/computer-graphics-programs-using-c-programming/2d-animation-computer-graphics-programs/2d-rotation-program-using-c-programming) but that resulted in the triangle being flipped about the second vertex, which seems odd, but then that technique works with p and q being the x and y coordinates of the second vertex.

Thanks for taking a look!

**Solved:**  Here is the corrected function.  It assumes you have calculated the center of the triangle.  I used the 1/3(x1 + x2 + x3), 1/3(y1 + y2 + y3) method described on the Wikipedia article on Centroids.

```
- (CGPoint)rotatePoint:(CGPoint)currentPoint byRadians:(float)radiansOfRotation
{
    float deltaX = currentPoint.x - center.x;
    float deltaY = currentPoint.y - center.y;
    float radius = sqrtf(powf(deltaX, 2.0) + powf(deltaY, 2.0));
    float currentAngle = atan2f( deltaY, deltaX );
    float newAngle = currentAngle + radiansOfRotation;
    float newRun = radius * cosf(newAngle);
    float newX = center.x + newRun;
    float newRise = radius * sinf(newAngle);
    float newY = center.y + newRise;
    return CGPointMake(newX, newY);
}
```

Of noteworthy relevance to why the first code listing did not work was that the arguments to atan2 were reversed.  Also, the correct calculation of the delta values was reversed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're forgetting to multiply by the radius of the circle. Also, since the Y axis points down in the UIKit coordinate system, you have to subtract instead of add the radians and negate the y coordinate at the end. And you need to use atan2 only gives output in the range -pi/2 to pi/2:

```
float currentAngle = atan2f(deltaY, deltaX);
float newAngle = currentAngle - radians;
float radious = sqrtf(powf(deltaX, 2.0) + powf(deltaY, 2.0));
float newX = radius * cosf(newAngle) + vertex.x;
float newY = -1.0 * radius * sinf(newAngle) + vertex.y;
```

Comment: Thanks, yuji, for pointing that out.  I integrated that into the code .  It makes part of it correct, but now my new vertices coordinates are way out of whack.  I put in lots of logging messages and work the math backwards to see if the inputs can be recalculated.  I'm not there yet, but I think you've helped!

Comment: My pleasure. I found another issue—try the new edited version above.

Comment: You're moving faster than I am!  I'm putting in logging statements to see where my mistake is being made.  I was building an awareness that Y was going in the wrong direction, but hadn't gotten there yet.  Were you changing the sign because they Y axis on iOS grows bigger going downward, unlike cartesian coordinates?

Comment: Yup, exactly. But then I had to spend a couple minutes thinking about trigonometry in my head to make sure it was right :P

Comment: There was another mistake in there, but this time I even drew the triangles, so I'm pretty sure it's right.

Comment: I'm drawing it out on graph paper.  At present, though, I'm wondering if my premise that I can add radians together even makes sense.  The theory was that by adding the radians of rotation to the radian angle of a vertex to the center of the triangle, I would have the new location for the vertex.  However, in iOS coordinate terms, I have a gesture rotation of -0.00274 resulting in an x displacement of over 200 points.  That doesn't meet my definition of "math makes sense."

Comment: One more thing I noticed before I call it a night. Hopefully it works; if not I'll take another look tomorrow.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7666/discussion-between-tobinjim-and-yuji)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is embedded now in the original question. Gun shy about proper decorum ;-)